# Laravel echo listen for whisper function not working

Tags: vue.js, pusher, laravel-echo

I'm building a live chat app, but I found that `listenforwhisper` function is not working, but `.whisper()` function works fine, pusher also received client typing event.
[image]

Here is my code:

For listen whisper:

```
Echo.private(`messages.${this.user.id}`)
    .listen("NewMessage", (e) => {
      this.handleIncoming(e.message);
    })
    .listenForWhisper("typing", (e) => {
      if(e.name !='') {
        this.typeStatus = 'typing .........'
      }
      else {
        this.typeStatus = ''
      }
      console.log(this.typeStatus);
    });
```

For whisper:

```
watch: {
    message() {
      Echo.private(`messages.${this.user.id}`)
      .whisper("typing", {
        name: this.message
      });
    }
  }
```

For channel:

```
Broadcast::channel('messages.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

Theoretically, my console will return the `typeStatus`, but I got nothing in my console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whisper works like broadcastToOthers. You're now trying to listen for the current users whispers. You should have a room where the whisper goes to and there should be multiple clients there to recieve. Now your channel is tied to the user and no-one else can see the messages that go through that channel.

Comment: so you mean i have to have a channel that id is using a room id, and this room id will accept both the sender and receiver and return true??

Comment: Exactly, you can keep the room ids in database and add them as a manyToMany relationship for both users.

Comment: `broadcastToOthers` doesn't seem like it's true. I used it, and opening the same page in two tabs listens to the current user's whisper. I think developer should handle the whisper when showing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I step in same issue. I got 2 channels and 2 users. I set a interval with wisper

```
setInterval(() => {
            channel.whisper('typing', {
                message: 'hola!'
            });
        }, 3000);

channel.listenForWhisper('typing', (e) => {
                console.log('Typing');
                console.log(e);
            })
```

The thing was that I was receving events but won't be able to see the output from listenForWhisper until I connect the second user to the channel.

[image]

Once the second user is connected, it's works just fine. So I leaved her if you got same issue.

Comment: I don't see how setTimeOut resolves any logical problem here

Comment: It's not setTimeout, it's setInterval. They're using it to simulate a typing event every 3 seconds.